# How to define a generic function that takes a Mutex<T>?

Tags: generics, rust

This simple function locks a `f64` and updates the value

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn bar() {
    let a = Mutex::new(1.0);
    let mut b = a.lock().unwrap();
    *b = 2.0;
    foo(a, 3.0);
}
```

I would like to encapsulate the behaviour into a function but I cannot figure out how to specify the `where` clause for T

```
fn foo<T, V>(lockable_param: T, value: V)
// where
//    T: Mutex??,
{
    let mut lock = lockable_param.lock().unwrap();
    *lock = value;
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you mean `.lock().unwrap()`? 2) How are `V` and `T` related, why are you trying to assign a `V` where a `T` would be expected? In your first example, both `T` and `V` seem to be the same type `f64`.

Comment: 1) yes - fixed 2) In this case yes, but in my real code, V is not the underlying type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need as many parameters, just use `Mutex<T>` and `T` for parameters. I presume you will need to receive a reference and not a value since you are not returning anything. This should work:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn bar() {
    let a = Mutex::new(1.0);
    let mut b = a.lock().unwrap();
    *b = 2.0;
    foo(&a, 3.0);
}

fn foo<T>(lockable_param: &Mutex<T>, value: T) {
    let mut lock = lockable_param.lock().unwrap();
    *lock = value;
}
```